# Python 2.7 IO.Open Readline with extra character \

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, io

I am trying to open a .c file with the below content

```
web_test("LunchType",
         "LB=\"foodType\":\"",
         "RB=\",",
         "ORD=ALL",
         "SEARCH=ALL",
         LAST);
```

used the following code to open and read the content

```
def open_file_read_line_by_line(self,file_to_read):
    with io.open(file_to_read,"rt",encoding='utf-8') as f:
        while True:
            readfile = f.readline()
            # readfile = f.read()
            if not readfile:
                break
            yield readfile
    f.close()
```

when reading the second line, I get the following content

```
"LB=\\"foodType\\":\\"",
```

There is an additonal '\' infront of '\' . Can anyone suggest how can I correct this ?

Comment: you're seeing the representation of the string. Try to `print` it, you'll see that there's only one slash (note: your snippet doesn't show how you get this output, I suppose you're putting this in a list then print the list)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you were right.